# If statement invoked twice inside else statement in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute PowerShell script which this code:

```
    function Invoke-InstallationOfANewBuild() {   
    param (
           $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld = "$($env:USERPROFILE)\Desktop\",
           $PlaceOnANetworkDriveWhereBuildsAreHeld = "\\r\P\Al\OSystem\D B\20\x64"
           )
    begin  { 
            Write-Verbose -Message "Searching for a build with the biggest CL number a in build name in local folder." -Verbose    
            $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnADesktop = Get-ChildItem $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -Like '*OSystemInstaller_20*' | ForEach-Object {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                Name = $_.FullName 
            } 
            } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1

            Write-Verbose -Message "Searching for a build with the biggest CL number in a build name on a network drive." -Verbose
            $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnANetworkDrive = Get-ChildItem $PlaceOnANetworkDriveWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | ForEach-Object {
                New-Object psobject -Property @{
                No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
                Name = $_.FullName 
            }
            } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1

                Write-Verbose -Message "Comparison of two hash sums. Please, wait." -Verbose

            if ($CheckClNumberOfABuildOnADesktop)
             {
                $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnDesktop = Get-MyFileHash $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnADesktop -Algorithm MD5
                $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive = Get-MyFileHash $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnANetworkDrive -Algorithm MD5

             }
            else {
                Write-Verbose -Message "There are no O System 20-1 (dev branch) builds in specified local folder. Extracting hash of the newest build in the network folder..." -Verbose
                $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive = Get-MyFileHash $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnANetworkDrive -Algorithm MD5

             }

            if ($GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnDesktop.MD5 -ne $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive.MD5)
                   {
                     Write-Verbose -Message "Hash sum of a file which is placed on the desktop and file in the network drive are different or there is no O System 20-1 build in specified local folder. The newest build will be copied from the network folder to to the local folder." -Verbose
                   }
            else {
                     Write-Verbose -Message "Hash sum of a file which is placed on the desktop and a file on the network drive are the same. No need to copy anything." -Verbose
                 }
            }
       process { 

           if ($GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnDesktop.MD5 -eq $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive.MD5){ 
                    Write-Verbose -Message "Installation... Please, wait." -Verbose

            Get-ChildItem $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -Like '*OSystemInstaller_20*' | ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
            No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
            Name = $_.FullName
            }
            } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | ForEach-Object { & $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}             
        }          

            else {
                    Write-Verbose -Message "The newest build doesn't exist in specified folder. Downloading, please wait." -Verbose

            $SelectTheNewestBuildInFolder = Get-ChildItem  $PlaceOnANetworkDriveWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
            No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
            Name = $_.FullName 
            }
            } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld
            }

            $HashNumberOfCopiedBuild = Get-MyFileHash $SelectTheNewestBuildInFolder -Algorithm MD5

            if ($HashNumberOfCopiedBuild.MD5 -eq $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive.MD5) {
                Write-Verbose -Message "Hash sum of the copied file and hash sum of original file are the same. Builds are the same." -Verbose

                Write-Verbose -Message "Installation... Please, wait." -Verbose

            Get-ChildItem $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -Like '*OSystemInstaller*' | ForEach-Object {
            New-Object psobject -Property @{
            No = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
            Name = $_.FullName
            }
            } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | ForEach-Object {& $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}     
            }
            else {
                Write-Verbose -Message "Hash sum of the copied file and hash sum of original file are different. Builds are the same." -Verbose
                 } # [Block moved]
             }     
        }     
             Invoke-InstallationOfANewBuild
```

But the `if` statement in last else statement works twice (so that installation process is invoked twice). How can I put if statement inside `else` statement so that it can be invoked only once? Example

1) If value is `true` in the  `else` than execute installation and stop the script
2) If value is `false` in the `else` than move to `if` in `else` and execute installation from there.

Comment: Write a very short script that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. (Your script sample contains variable data we don't have.)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I have posted the hole script.

Comment: I didn't say to post the whole script; I said to post a very short script that contains only the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Done. And don't ask to short it again because in that case logic will be lost completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
process { 
if ($GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnDesktop.MD5 -ne $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive.MD5) { 

    Get-ChildItem  $PlaceOnANetworkDriveWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            No   = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
            Name = $_.FullName 
        }
    } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | Copy-Item -Destination $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld
}          
$CheckClNumberOfABuildOnADesktop = Get-ChildItem  $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -NotMatch '.*NoDB\.exe$' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        No   = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
        Name = $_.FullName 
    }
} | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 

$HashNumberOfTheCopiedBuild = Get-MyFileHash $CheckClNumberOfABuildOnADesktop -Algorithm MD5

if ($HashNumberOfTheCopiedBuild.MD5 -eq $GetHashOfFileWhichIsPlacedOnNetworkDrive.MD5) {

    Write-Verbose -Message "Installation... Please, wait." -Verbose

    Get-ChildItem $PathToTheLocalFolderWhereBuildsAreHeld -Filter *.exe | Where-Object Name -Like '*OrthoSystemInstaller*' | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object psobject -Property @{
            No   = [int]([regex]::Match($_.Name, '(?<=CL)\d+').Value)
            Name = $_.FullName
        }
    } | Sort-Object No -Descending | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name -First 1 | ForEach-Object {& $_ -s2 -sp"-SilentInstallation=standalone -UpdateMaterials=yestoall -UpgradeDBIfRequired=yes"}     
}
else {
    Write-Verbose -Message "H" -Verbose
  }
 }     
}
```

All I did - remove installation from first `if` and put to the second `if`.